# Positions on grid 'used'

Tags: algorithm

I have a puzzle to solve which involves taking input which is size of grid.  Grid is always square.  Then a number of points on the grid are provided and the squares on the grid are 'taken' if they are immediately left or right or above or below.

Eg imagine a grid 10 x 10.  If points are (1,1) bottom left and (10,10) top right, then if a point (2,1) is given then square positions left and right (10 squares) and above and below (another 9 squares) are taken.  So using simple arithmetic, if grid is n squared then n + (n-1) squares will be taken on first point provided.

But it gets complicated if other points are provided as input.  Eg if next point is eg (5,5) then another 19 squares will be 'taken' minus thos squares overlapping other point.  so it gets complex.  and of course a point say (3,1) could be provided which overlaps more.

Is there an algorithm for this type of problem?

Or is it simply a matter of holding a 2 dimensional array and placing an x for each taken square.  then at end just totting up taken (or non-taken) squares.  That would work but I was wndering if there is an easier way.

Comment: How big can the square become? Also, what language are you using to solve this?

Comment: there is no bound to size but in reality is unlikely to be massive - ie below 10000 squared.  Is language relevant?  I am looking for an algorithm.  will probably write in C but could choose another language.

Comment: ok, that's fair. In that case the algorithm posted below should work.

Comment: update - one of the test cases is a grid of 935821.  I was attempting to allocate memory for an array of that squared - but fails to allocate that amount of memory.  So I will have to re-think that.

Answer (score 1):

Keep two sets: X (storing all x-coords) and Y (storing all y-coords). The number of squares taken will be n * (|X| + |Y|) - |X| * |Y|. This follows because each unique x-coord removes a column of n squares, and each unique y-coord removes a row of n squares. But this counts the intersections of the removed rows and columns twice, so we subtract |X| * |Y| to account for this.

Comment: I don't understand the n * (|X| + |Y|) - |X| * |Y| notation you use.  Can you elaborate a bit on that please and how you would eg work out for a simple 4 x 4 grid with eg one point chosen.

Comment: |X| is the number of elements in set X.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to keep track of the positions that are taken in some data structure, for example a set.

- At the first step this involves adding n + (n - 1) squares to that data structure.
- At the second (third, fourth) step etc this involves checking for each square at the horizontal and vertical line for the given (x, y) whether it's already in the data structure. If not then you add it to the data structure. Otherwise, if the point is already in there, then it was taken in an earlier step.

We can actually see that the first step is just a special case of the other rounds because in the first round no points are taken yet. So in general the algorithm is to keep track of the taken points and to add any new ones to a data structure.

So in pseudocode:

- Create a data structure taken_points = empty data structure (e.g., a set)

Whenever you're processing a point (x, y):

- Set a counter = 0.
- Given a point (x, y):

  - for each point (px, py) on the horizontal and vertical lines that intersect with (x, y):
  - check if that point is already in taken_points

    - if it is, then do nothing
    - otherwise, add (px, py) to taken_points and increment counter

You've now updated taken_points to contain all the points that are taken so far and counter is the number of points that were taken in the most recent round.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it without using large space:-

```
rowVisited[n] = {0} 
colVisited[n] = {0}

totalrows = 0 and totalcol = 0  for total rows and columns visited

total = 0;  // for point taken for x,y


given point (x,y)  

   if(!rowVisited[x]) {

        total = total + n - totalcol;
   }

   if(!colVisited[y]) {

         total = total + n-1 - totalrows + rowVisited[x];

   }

   if(!rowVisited[x]) {

        rowVisited[x]  = 1;
        totalrows++;
   }

   if(!colVisited[x]) {

       colVisited[x] = 1;
       totalcol++;
   }


print total
```